# My DIV resizer doesn't work on touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project where I need to resize a set of DIV containers by sliding a single manual control.

I've harvested code from other projects to achieve what I think will work and in my testing, I discovered it doesn't work on touch screens.  Unfortunately I do not understand the actual differences between a click-hold-drag and a finger drag, but evidently there is enough so that my slider doesn't work on the touch screen device.

I have read many questions on this site, and most of what I have found has to do with resizing divs or tables automatically based on device screen size.  My question applies specifically to manually moving a slider to resize the containers' x/y axes.

I am not married to any of the below code, so I am open to suggestion if anyone has a better way of achieving the goal.

```js
$(function() {
  var topH;
  var leftW;
  $("#grab").draggable({ // vert
    axis: "x",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      shiftInitial = ui.position.left;
      leftW = $("#left").width();
      topH = $("#top").height();
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      var shift = ui.position.left;
      $("#left div").height(topH - shift / 8);
      $("#left div").width(leftW + shift);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#grab {
  /* grab bar */
  padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
  margin: 1em 1em 1em 3em;
  width: 3em;
  height: 5em;
  background: url(https://c7.uihere.com/icons/893/690/568/drag-vertical-f64d278f0957b61937f1aa604020339d.svg) no-repeat right;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

#top {
  /* this is the container */
  margin: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 6.25em;
  min-width: 12em;
  max-width: 45em;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 6.25em;
  border: solid #A8AFB4 .0625em;
  border-left: .7em solid blue;
  border-radius: .375em;
}

#left {
  /* to shove the grab icon over */
  width: 11em;
  height: 1em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="left">
    <div id="top">Div 1</div>
    <div id="top">Div 2</div>
    <div id="top">Div 3</div>
    <div id="top">Div 4</div>
    <div id="top">Div 5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grab"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [a working codepen](https://codepen.io/miaxcova/pen/ewqjmB).

I have tried on both Android and Apple devices and trying to drag the slider does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I finally found an easy solution to my problem.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I simply added that Jquery UI add on to my project and it works perfectly!

Quoted from the Touch Punch homepage:

> Touch Punch works by using simulated events to map touch events to their mouse event analogs.